# How to get the time of download webpage with python?

Tags: python-3.x

as the title，i want to know how to get the time of download webpage with python,do you have some suggestion?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

requests is an HTTP library for python. Maybe you can use it to measure load times. Make sure to install the library in your development environment.

```
pip install requests
```

code:

```
import requests  

request_time = requests.get("http://example.com").elapsed.total_seconds()     
print(request_time)
```

Comment: but,isn't  the total_time? I just want to get the time of download web page.